# Typescipt: how to access class-contants from typeorm getManager.query()

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am relatively new to the typeORM/Typescript world. I have a service class to serve a resource as follows:

```
import { Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

class MyServiceClass {

//static readonly sqlStr = `SELECT MAINTABLE.* WITH LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH TWO MORE TABLES `;

async findAll(limit?: number) {
    const mgr = getManager();
    const retRows = await mgr.query(
      `
      SELECT MAINTABLE.* WITH LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH TWO MORE TABLES

          ${limit ? `FETCH NEXT ${limit} ROWS ONLY` : ''}
      `,
    );
    return retRows;
  }

async findOne(id: number) {
    const mgr = getManager();
    const retRow = await mgr.query(
      `
      SELECT MAINTABLE.* WITH LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH TWO MORE TABLES

        ${id ? ` WHERE MAINTABLE.MAIN_ID = ${id}` : ''}
      `,
    );
    return retRow;
  }

}
```

I would like to remove the sql statement from each function but keep the filtering logic. Instead I want to use the MyServiceClass.sqlStr inside mgr.query() function. It would be great if someone points me out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use repository tools from typeorm module:

```
async findAll(limit?: number) {
    const entities = await this.entityRepository.findAll(
      { where: { id: 1 } }, relations: ['someRelation'], sort: {id: 'DESC'},
      /* you can create very advanced requests */
    );

    return entities;
  }
```

or with query builder:

```
async findAll(limit?: number) {
    const rows = await this.entityRepository
       .createQueryBuilder('Entity')
       .leftJoinAndSelect('Entity.relation', 'relation')
       .where('relation.id = :id', {id: 1})
       /* any query condition here */
       .getMany() // or .getSql() or whatever you want

    return rows;
  }
```

more detailed about how you can set up typeorm repository [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)

more about find options [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)

query builder docs [here](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_query_builder_querybuilder_.querybuilder.html)